# setOnClickListener on a TextView inside a Cardview

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm having some trouble implementing a setOnClickListener on a TextView inside a Cardview.I use this Cardview to populate a recicleview.
I have tried setting up the listener in the onBindViewHolder,but i can't see the log.

Single Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:clickable="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fotoUser"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#f9fbff"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:minHeight="300dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fotoUser"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">


                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_diaf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_weight="0.03"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="1.0"
                    android:id="@+id/txtDiaf"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_tempi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_weight="0.03"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="1sec"
                    android:id="@+id/txtTempo"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_iso"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_weight="0.03"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="100"
                    android:id="@+id/txtIso"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_fl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_weight="0.03"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="100mm"
                    android:id="@+id/txtFl"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="USERNAME"
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DESCRIZIONE"
                android:id="@+id/descFoto"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_like"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/likes"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/descFoto"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/descFoto" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NL"
                android:id="@+id/likes"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
                android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
                android:layout_above="@+id/spazio"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/spazio"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_below="@+id/descFoto"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnLIKE"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_nolike"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.06"
                android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

List->

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:background="#fffffc">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listaFoto"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:divider="#fff9fa" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Bind->

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final SeguitiFragment_FotoADP.FotoViewHolder holder,final int position) {
    SeguitiFragment_Foto fotoS = foto.get(position);

    //.....
    holder.nomeUser.setText(fotoS.getUser());
    holder.nomeUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Click","Effettuato");
        }
    });
    //.........

    }
```

Adapter->

```
public class SeguitiFragment_FotoADP extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SeguitiFragment_FotoADP.FotoViewHolder>{

private List<SeguitiFragment_Foto> foto;
private Context c;
private String NomeFile;

public SeguitiFragment_FotoADP(List<SeguitiFragment_Foto> foto,Context c) {
    this.foto = foto;
    this.c=c;
}


@Override
public SeguitiFragment_FotoADP.FotoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_subfoto, parent, false);

    return new FotoViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SeguitiFragment_FotoADP.FotoViewHolder holder,final int position) {
    SeguitiFragment_Foto fotoS = foto.get(position);


    if(fotoS.getDiaframma()==-1){
        holder.diaf.setText("--");
    }else{
        holder.diaf.setText(fotoS.getDiaframma()+"");
    }

    if(fotoS.getIso()==-1){
        holder.iso.setText("--");
    }else{
        holder.iso.setText(fotoS.getIso()+"");
    }

    holder.nomeUser.setText(fotoS.getUser());
    holder.nomeUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Click","Effettuato");
        }
    });
    holder.desc.setText(fotoS.getDescrizione());
    holder.tempo.setText(fotoS.getTempi()+ "sec");
    holder.fl.setText(fotoS.getMillimetri()+"mm");


    NomeFile=fotoS.getIdFoto();

    File file = new File (c.getFilesDir(), NomeFile+".jpg");
    if (!file.exists ()) {
        downloadFTP ftp = new downloadFTP(fotoS.getIdFoto(), holder);
        ftp.execute();
    }else{
        settaImmagine(holder);
    }



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return foto.size();
}


public static class FotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView immagine;
    public TextView nomeUser;
    public TextView desc;
    public TextView diaf;
    public TextView tempo;
    public TextView iso;
    public TextView fl;
    public ImageView like;

    public FotoViewHolder(View convertView) {
        super(convertView);

        nomeUser=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        desc=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.descFoto);
        immagine=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fotoUser);
        diaf=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDiaf);
        iso=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtIso);
        fl=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFl);
        tempo=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTempo);
        like=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnLIKE);


    }


public void settaImmagine(FotoViewHolder v){
    File file = new File(c.getFilesDir(), NomeFile + ".jpg");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    v.immagine.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

}

Thank You!

Comment: are you performing item click listener on recyclerview?

Comment: TextView by default is not clickable so make it clickable by adding `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: I've Tried android:clickable="true",it doesn't work.

Comment: can you please post your adapter class?

Comment: Edited. Thank you.

Comment: you want to have that as linkable text?

Comment: Yes,sorta.It should open a new fragment...

Comment: try to use onlick on image view. if it is working then the problem is you have to make imageview clickable false.

Comment: Tried,putting on the imageview android:clickable="true" and setting the listener (imageview .setOnclick....), but nothing appears.... maybe it's a problem on the layout?

Comment: @Punllo try after removing cardView and test it is working or not? If working then problem is in cardView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try to set `onClickListener` after `setText` on your `onBindViewHolder`.

**Refer this.**

```
 holder.mTextView.setText(mValues.get(position));
 holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("Click", "Effettuato");
     }
 });
```

> As per your code change this.

```
holder.nomeUser.setText(fotoS.getUser());
holder.nomeUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("Click","Effettuato");
    }
});
```

**EDIT 1:**

> In your FotoViewHolder `overRide` this before `settaImmagine` function.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return super.toString() + " '" + nomeUser.getText();
}
```

Comment: @Punllo Check my answer as per your code i have added just move your `onClickListener` below `setText`. I have checked my side and log is showing as given.

Comment: @Punllo I have checked it my side and `Log` is showing as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.In the main post is already as you suggested,and the code doesn't works...i'm missing something?

Comment: I've added the code,but unfortunately the log doesn't shows up.

Comment: @Punllo Try your luck i don't be able to assume now. this all tricks i have checked first and applied my side and it's working Log fine.

Comment: @Punllo I have upvoted your Question. you also upvote my answer thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Use
in xml

```
<TextView
       <-- other attributes -->
      android:clickable="true"
       />
```

in Adapter

```
nomeUser= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.**id**);
```

and finally

```
holder.nomeUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Click","Effettuato");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,it doesn't work, please see the edit

Comment: @Punllo Is your texview is filled with Text?

Comment: Yes,i set up  the text with setText()

Comment: @Punllo If text is empty then width of textview will be  and you wont be able to click it. So make sure you have non empty text in textview.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your 
`class FotoViewHolder`

`nomUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Click","Effettuato");
        }
    });`

if you want to identify different `nomUser` ,you can get the adapter position by using this code

`int pos = getAdapterPosition();`

Comment: are you able to see your recyclerview datas ? @Punllo

Comment: are you adding this code inside your
`public FotoViewHolder(View convertView)` 
method ?
If this is not working try to give a Toast and see if you're getting any Toast when click on the Textview
`Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
Toast inside onClick.

Answer (score 0):

**This is your TextView in your layout :**

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="USERNAME"
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

You don't have `android:clickable="true"` . Add `android:clickable="true"` to your required `TextView`
and in your onBindViewHolder add :

```
holder.nomeUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Click","clicked");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First add below property in you parent(Means parent Linear-layout of your singleItem) of Single Item layout,

**android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"**

and then try as below,

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final SeguitiFragment_FotoADP.FotoViewHolder holder,final int position) 
{
     SeguitiFragment_Foto fotoS = foto.get(position);
     bind(position,fotoS);
}
```

now in your **FotoViewHolder** class make method as below,

```
public void bind(int pos, SeguitiFragment_Foto fotoS) {

nomeUser.setText(fotoS.getUser());
nomeUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("Click","Effettuato");
    }
});

}
```